# Função que retorne mais de uma variavel em c

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, return

Eu preciso fazer uma função que receba 3 floats e retorne a média, o maior numero dentre os 3 e a diferença entre a média e o maior. Eu tentei fazer o retorno por um ponteiro mas uma das variaveis não é retornada corretamente e não consigo achar explicações sobre no google, nem maneiras alternativas para resolver o meu problema. 
Eu sei que deve ter outras maneiras de fazer esse programa, mas no enunciado eu tenho algumas restrições: não posso usar variaveis globais, incluindo struct, os paramtros da função devem ser apenas 3 floats. O que eu queria saber é o que esta errado neste programa, pq não esta dando certo? Se é sobre a utilização do ponteiro ou a logica é falha...

```
//a comparação de valores não está correta
//o valor de mmd[1] não está sendo retornada corretamente

float *func_mmd(float a, float b, float c)//func_media_maior_diferenca
{
    float mmd[3];

    mmd[0]=(a+b+c)/3;//media

    mmd[1]=a;
    if(a>b || a>c)//comparação maior numero
    {
        mmd[1]=a;
    }
    else
        if(b>c || b>a)
        {
            mmd[1]=b;
        }
        else
            if(a==b && a==c && b==c)
            {
                mmd[1]=a;
            }
            else
            {mmd[1]=c;}


    mmd[2]=mmd[0]-mmd[1];//diferença

    printf("%f",mmd[1]);//este printf é só pra eu saber o que está sendo armazenada na variavel que calcula  o maior numero
    return (mmd);
}

int main()
{
    float a,b,c,*mmd;

    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    scanf("%f",&c);

    mmd=func_mmd(a,b,c);
    printf("\nA media eh:%f",mmd[0]);
    printf("\nO maior valor eh: %f",mmd[1]);
    printf("\nA diferenca entre a media e o maior numero eh: %f",mmd[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O problema é que você está retornando o ponteiro de uma variável automática (float mmd[3]) que deixa de existir assim que a função func_mmd() retorna. Uma solução simples é declarar mmd na função main() e passá-lo como um parâmetro float mmd[], assim é garantido que a área de memória de mmd existirá durante toda a execução do programa.